# LibGdx: How to check if VSync is enabled

Tags: libgdx, vsync

I am just about finished my options screen, the only thing I need is some way of detecting if Vsync is enabled or not.

I'm using LibGdx 1.5. I have tried to find an access to wglSwapIntervals, but haven't found one. Libgdxs API only allows a setVsync options that accepts a Boolean.

If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set the VSync to on at the start of your game and create a variable within your code that will store the VSync boolean. Then if a user changes their VSync settings you update your variable as well. This will also allow you to save a user's VSync option because you can store your boolean when the game exits and when it restarts, set VSync to the stored variable.

Comment: Looks like I will have to go this route. Was hoping for something a little more engine level, but doesn't appear that way. Thanks!